# Which encryption method is that?

Tags: encryption, decryption, encoding

I have seen it lots of times around the web, but I don't know how it's called.
It has a numeric secret key, and the output is composed only by this characters; ".,:;!%&#".

I searched all the web and I found only this program: http://resources.digitalspaghetti.net/downloads/Tonycrypt.zip

This is an example:
plaintext: "test"
key: "1"
output: ".&:;,:#%:.&:"

Comment: You found something from a suspicious site and used it ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any simple cryptanalysis against it? If not do some research and give it a go.

My guess would be it is a simple substitution combined with a caesar shift...if so it is trivially simple and I doubt you have seen it used as real-world encryption anywhere.